# Solrにおけるあいまい検索の実装について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr

Ruby on RailsでSunspotを通してSolrの検索システムを作っています。

検索自体は問題なくできるのですが、より高度な検索を実装したいと思っており改修しております。
現状の検索ですと、「渋谷駅」と検索すると、「渋谷」は検索結果に出てきません。
同様に、「東京都」で検索すると、「東京」はマッチしません。

「渋谷駅」と検索したら「渋谷」を含むものも検索結果に出てくるように改修したいです。

困っているので、もしどなたかご存知でしたら教えて頂けないでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solrをセットアップして試してみましたが、フィールドが

- org.apache.solr.schema.TextField のときは、"渋谷駅"で「渋谷」を含むドキュメントが検索できる
- org.apache.solr.schema.StrField のときは、"渋谷駅"でも"渋谷"でもヒットせず、"*渋谷*"でなら検索できる

という感じでした。(コンソールのquery画面で確認)

日本語用のフィールドであれば、JapanesePartOfSpeechStopFilterFactoryを使って特定の品詞を落とすことができるようです。デフォルトで助詞などが除外されるようになっていますが、`lang/stoptags_ja`を編集することで任意の品詞を除外対象に追加できます。`名詞-接尾-地域`

を追加すると「市」とか「駅」とかが落ちました。(コンソールのAnalysisで確認)

Comment: ありがとうございます！
org.apache.solr.schema.TextFieldで試してみます。

Comment: 恐らくschema.xmlにorg.apache.solr.schema.TextFieldを記述するのだと思うのですが、どこに記述すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" omitNorms="true"/>
を
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true"/>
としましたら、
「渋谷駅」で「渋谷」にヒットするようになりました。
但し、以前として「東京都」は「東京」を含む文章にはヒットしません。
もし、「東京都」で「東京」にヒットするような方法をご存知でしたら、ご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

例えば都道府県や市町村、駅名程度の語尾を無視する程度であれば検索ワードを渡す時に

```
search_text = search_text.gsub(/駅$/,'').gsub(/都$/,'')
```

のようにすれば良いと思います。

形態素解析を行い、それぞれの単語に対しての検索結果を求めるのであれば全く違ったアプローチが必要になってくるでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
最終的に回答が見つからないようであれば、こちらの方法で対処する予定でした。